# python, select random #k numbers from (1, n) excluding numbers in list

Tags: python, algorithm

For a given exclude_list = [3, 5, 8], n = 30, k = 5

I'd like to pick 5(k) random numbers between 1 and 30.
But I should not pick numbers in the exclude_list

Suppose exclude_list, n could be potentially large.

When there's no need for exclusion, it is easy to get k random samples

```
rand_numbers = sample(range(1, n), k)
```

So to get the answer, I could do

```
sample(set(range(1, n)) - set(exclude_numbers), k)
```

I read that range keeps one number in memory at a time.
I'm not quite sure how it affects the two lines above.

The first question is, does the following code puts all n numbers in memory or does it put each number at a time?

```
rand_numbers = sample(range(1, n), k)
```

2nd question is, if the above code indeed puts one number at a time in memory, can I do the similar with the additional constraint of the exclusion list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample notes in [`sample`'s docstring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> To choose a sample in a range of integers, use range as an argument.
>   This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a
>   large population:   sample(range(10000000), 60)

I can test this on my machine:

```
In [11]: sample(range(100000000), 3)
Out[11]: [70147105, 27647494, 41615897]

In [12]: list(range(100000000))  # crash/takes a long time
```

---

One way to sample with an exclude list efficiently is to use the same range trick but "hop over" the exclusions (we can do this in O(k * log(`len(exclude_list)`)) with the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect
import random

def sample_excluding(n, k, excluding):
    # if we assume excluding is unique and sorted we can avoid the set usage...
    skips = [j - i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(set(excluding)))]
    s = random.sample(range(n - len(skips)), k)
    return [i + bisect.bisect_right(skips, i) for i in s]
```

and we can see it working:

```
In [21]: sample_excluding(10, 3, [2, 4, 7])
Out[21]: [6, 3, 9]

In [22]: sample_excluding(10, 3, [1, 2, 8])
Out[22]: [0, 4, 3]

In [23]: sample_excluding(10, 6, [1, 2, 8])
Out[23]: [0, 7, 9, 6, 3, 5]
```

Specifically we've done this without using O(n) memory:

```
In [24]: sample_excluding(10000000, 6, [1, 2, 8])
Out[24]: [1495143, 270716, 9490477, 2570599, 8450517, 8283229]
```

Comment: Note: This code also assumes, but doesn't enforce, that excluding is a subset of range(n).